# Is it possible to run stored procedure to set value in update statement - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering if its possible to execute a stored procedure in an update statement in TSQL.

I want to execute a stored procedure that will set the `CategoryID` for the number table, passing in the number from the row the update statement is currently on.

So something like:

```
UPDATE [TelephoneNumberManagement].[dbo].[Number]
SET [CategoryID] = exec goldennumbers2 [Number];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

You could do this if it were a function:

```
UPDATE [TelephoneNumberManagement].[dbo].[Number]
SET [CategoryID] = goldennumbers2([Number]);
```

Just keep in mind that a function can't have side-effects.  If you're trying to run a bunch of DML statements in that procedure you should:

- A) Use a trigger, if you have dependencies in other tables that need to be kept in-sync with your `Number` table. Even so you might want to...
- B) Rethink your design. This feels like trying to mix set-based and iterative programming practices. There's almost certainly a more *pure* solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, there are some options like user-defined functions.  Triggers might be able to do what you want, depending upon what you're trying to do and why.

What exactly does your goldennumbers2 procedure do?